# How to authorize a remote access for a specific ip in the LAN?

Tags: windows, configuration

I'm using XP,

How can another pc in the LAN access by \name\directory without typing password?

Now he has to type in the password each time to access.

Answer (score 2):

[here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/304040) has a good guide on setting up file sharing and the various options you have.  The best way is to have a matching account/password on both machines.  The guide shows how to use the guest account to allow access for everyone.

EDIT: Okay, that isn't a very useful guide, just lots of information on simple file sharing.  From what I can gather, on XP home, file sharing will always use the guest account.  On Pro you can change the option below, or you can change to always use guest the same as home.  The option is in the same place as below.

XP Pro has a default restriction that means a user account with no password can not be used for network access, it can be changed, again in the mmc snapin mentioned below.  I don't know if home enforces the same restriction, if it does then I fear you are stuck with it.  This restriction may mean that even the guest account requires a password to be entered.

There are two reasons why granting everyone access to the share doesn't work as you expect.  First is that although you have granted everyone access through the share, the NTFS file permissions are also checked, and they normally grant the Users group access, not everyone.  Second is that by default, everyone means all authenticated users.  There is an option under "Security Options" (Start -> Run, secpol.msc, then find security options on the left), for "Let everyone permissions apply to anonymous users" that allows you to change that.

Bear in mind that if you change everyone, or use guest, it means that EVERYONE can access that share.  the XP firewall will by default, only allow PC's on your LAN access to shares, I don't know what other firewalls will do.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a user with the same credentials (username/password) on the PC you want to access.

Give this user rights to the share.

If you don't want to limit it to particular users, give 'Everyone' rights to the share.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Windows networking requires authorization, and passwords are the most common way to do that.  You could try to clear the password for the account being used for access, but this isn't very secure.

I recommend leaving the password active, but have your friend **map the share he's accessing**.  There are two ways to do this:

1. With a scripted `net use` command (you could put the password in the script as part of the command).  Run it once, say, during your friend's login sequence; then the mapped share will be accessible for the rest of his session.
2. By mapping a network drive in Windows Explorer.

I recommend option 2; the password is stored encrypted in the user registry, and isn't exposed.  As a side benefit, it's pretty easy to do.

1. In Windows Explorer, go to the Tools menu and select `Map Network Drive`.
2. Select the drive letter, and in the "Folder" field type the address of the share to be accessed (eg `\\yourserver\yourshare` or `\\yourserver\yourshare\optional\path`).
3. Check the "Reconnect at Logon" box.
4. Click "connect using a different username".  In the popup, enter the username needed to access the share (eg `YOURSERVER\HISUSERNAME`), and the password.  Click OK.
5. Click OK in the first prompt.

This should be the only time your friend needs to enter the password.